# "Failed deleting inaccessible file" error while updating JCE editor pro to 2.8.1

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, jce

I am trying to update JCE editor pro to 2.8.1, but I get the following error:

> Joomla\Filesystem\File::delete: Failed deleting inaccessible file controller.php

We are using PHP7.2 and Joomla 3.9.13 It runs through the update, but stops at 100% and gives the error.

JCE Editor Pro is currently at version - 2.6.27

Comment: Thanks to Ryan at - https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/forum/100063-error-after-failed-update - I got a resolution

"The error Joomla is giving when it attempts to delete the files during the uninstall suggests a file ownership / permissions issue. This could occur when migrating the site.

Manually delete the following folders:

administrator/components/com_jce
components/com_jce
plugins/content/jce
plugins/editors/jce
plugins/extension/jce
plugins/fields/mediajce
plugins/installer/jce
plugins/quickicon/jce
plugins/system/jce
media/jce
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ryan at - joomlacontenteditor.net/support/forum, I got a resolution:

> The error Joomla is giv[en] when it attempts to delete the files during the uninstall suggests a file ownership / permissions issue.
>
> This could occur when migrating the site.
>
> Manually delete the following folders:
>
> - administrator/components/com_jce
> - components/com_jce
> - plugins/content/jce
> - plugins/editors/jce
> - plugins/extension/jce
> - plugins/fields/mediajce
> - plugins/installer/jce
> - plugins/quickicon/jce
> - plugins/system/jce media/jce